# How to install Perfino on heterogenious environment. (perfino server on windows, perfino agents on Linux)

Tags: perfino

Trying installe perfino server on windows box & agents on Linux

Perfino server should be able to connect to Perfino agents & monitor the Java threads.

Answer (score 0):

To install, just run the installer and follow the steps in the installer. At the end the server is started and the installation is completed in the browser. More help on installing is available at

https://resources.ej-technologies.com/perfino/help/doc/main/installing.html

To install agents, there is a "Add VMs" button at the top when you log into the perfino server that explains how to do that. More help on that topic is available at

https://resources.ej-technologies.com/perfino/help/doc/main/monitoring.html